# First line text-indent in sIFR

Tags: css, text, sifr, text-indent

I have a text block made whith sIFR and I want to indent the first line.

Look at this image to see what I want:

> `http://alltutorials.hi2.ro/testimonial.jpg`

I want the word WOW to be after the big quotes.

I searched the sIFR documention I used text-indent but it seems it doesn't work.

Thank's for the help,

Andrei

Paste the link because, it does not work directly.

Comment: the image shows a 403 Forbidden error...

Comment: Paste the url, I cant link to images directly on that server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with sIFR, but maybe a simple padding-left will do the trick? If it is treated as an inline element, it should not be repeated in the next few lines.

Comment: I know, but it might still work. sIFR listens to low-level CSS quite well.

Answer (score 1):

You can try styling it within sIFR, as Pekka said, something like this :

```
function sIFR_h1() 
{
  sIFR.replace(grau, {
  selector: 'h1, div.h1',
  css: 
      '.sIFR-root { letter-spacing:-1.66; font-size:42px; color: #36313d; [...]}'
    ,transparent: true  
    ,selectable: false      
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't think you can do this through CSS, though perhaps you could use the `modifyContentString()` callback to insert a few spaces?

Comment: It worked using text-indent, but this will be usefull to. Thank's